# How to wrap an element to the next line in html tables (in emails for Outlook)?

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to optimize my email for desktop Outlook.
The letter has a section in which, when creating a file, the necessary blocks are mapped into a specific line.
There can be a different number of these blocks.

The problem is that when these blocks don't fit into **tr**, they don't move to the next line. This was partially fixed by adding the **display: block** parameter to the **table** element, and **display: inline-block** to the **td** elements, which are mapped to the section.
Now it works everywhere, except desktop Outlook, where the blocks do not move to the next line if they do not fit, they simply map further, infinitely expanding the container width, depending on their number.

The code block looks like this:

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="padding: 24px 40px 0px 40px">
  <table
   border="0"
   cellpadding="0"
   cellspacing="0"
   width="100%"
   style="
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    mso-table-lspace: 0;
    mso-table-rspace: 0;
  "
  >
    <tr>
     <td style="padding-bottom: 24px">
       <table
         border="0"
         cellpadding="0"
         cellspacing="0"
         class="values-default"
         style="display: block"
       >
         <tr>
           <td style="padding: 12px; display: inline-block">
             <span> Block 1</span>
           </td>
           <td style="padding: 12px; display: inline-block">
             <span> Block 2 </span>
           </td>
           <td style="padding: 12px; display: inline-block">
             <span> Block 3 </span>
           </td>
           <td style="padding: 12px; display: inline-block">
             <span> Block 5 </span>
           </td>
           <td style="padding: 12px; display: inline-block">
             <span> Block 6 </span>
           </td>
           <td style="padding: 12px; display: inline-block">
             <span> Block 7 </span>
           </td>
           <td style="padding: 12px; display: inline-block">
             <span> Block 8 </span>
           </td>
           <td style="padding: 12px; display: inline-block">
             <span> Block 9 </span>
           </td>
          <td style="padding: 12px; display: inline-block">
            <span> Block 10 </span>
          </td>
          <td style="padding: 12px; display: inline-block">
            <span> Block 11 </span>
          </td>
          <td style="padding: 12px; display: inline-block">
            <span> Block 12 </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

These pictures show an example. The first screenshot is the expected behavior, the second is how Outlook renders it.

[image]

[image]

How to make items in Outlook wrap to a new line if they don`t fit the width of one line?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out. To make a flexible row in tables for Outlook, the block with elements shall look something like this:

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td
     colspan="2"
     style="padding: 24px 40px 0px 40px; background-color: pink; width: 200px"
    >
    <table
      border="0"
      cellpadding="0"
      cellspacing="0"
      width="100%"
      style="
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        mso-table-lspace: 0;
        mso-table-rspace: 0;
      "
    >
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 12px">
          <table align="left">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 12px">Some text here</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table align="left">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 12px">Some text here</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table align="left">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 12px">Some text here</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table align="left">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 12px">Some text here</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table align="left">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 12px">Some text here</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table align="left">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 12px">Some text here</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```